# VBA Functions and Arrays

Tags: vba

I am attempting to program a function in vba that calls other functions, and displays the output as a function array.  The called functions have been tested and work, but the function that calls the other functions returns #Value! erros.  Can the community provide any guidance on a possible fix?

```
Public Function OptionCall(OptionType As String, CallPutFlag As String, Value As Double, Delta As Double, Gamma As Double, _
Vega As Double, Theta As Double, Rho As Double)

    If OptionType = "KE_European" Then
        Value = KE_European(CallPutFlag, Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility)
        Delta = Delta_KE_European(CallPutFlag, Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility)
        Gamma = Gamma_KE_European(CallPutFlag, Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility)
        Vega = Vega_KE_European(CallPutFlag, Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility)
        Theta = Theta_KE_European(CallPutFlag, Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility)
        Rho = Rho_KE_European(CallPutFlag, Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility)
    End If

 OptionCall = Array(Value, Delta, Gamma, Vega, Theta, Rho)

End Function
```

Comment: Test your function by calling it from a sub, instead of from a worksheet.  You'll get more information about any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Unless these are global variables, the problem is most likely that these variables being passed as arguments to the functions are not declared and set in the function.

```
Underlying, Strike, Time, Rate, Volatility
```